# image flowing to next line instead of shrinking in a flexbox two-column layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a two columns layout with flexbox. In the second column there is an image with the property width=100% and min-width=100px. I want it to shrink until it reaches the min-width and then flow to next line. But it doesn't. It only shrinks to the native image width and then it flows to the next line, and only after flowing it starts shrinking again. How I can get it to shrink without flowing to the next line?
You can see my page here: https://codepen.io/davjdek/pen/WMKbrY

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* Safari */
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* Safari 6.1+ */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}

h1,
h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.containwrap {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

#container1 {
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 120px;
}

#endtitleline {
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%
}

#pagetitle {
  margin-left: auto;
}

#name,
#subtitle {
  text-align: right;
}

.header {
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* Safari */
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* Safari 6.1+ */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#pagetitle {
  font-family: 'Raleway', arial, sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

.central-img {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet" />

<header class="header">
  <aside class="sidebar">
  </aside>
  <section class="containwrap">
    <section class="container" id="container1">
      <div id="pagetitle">
        <h1 id="name">
          PORTFOLIO
        </h1>
        <h3 id="subtitle">
          FLEXBOX LAYOUT
        </h3>
      </div>
      <hr id="endtitleline">
    </section>

    <img src="https://s13.postimg.org/xkfa8rtvr/image.gif" class="central-img" />

  </section>
</header>
<section class="main">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code and see if it works

```
.containwrap {
    width: 10%;
}
```

i was able to get it to work i downloaded your codepen and this bit of code works

Comment: It works, but I can't understand the reason. Thank you!

Comment: its probably because if i bring down the width of the container than it gives it more space not really sure though

Answer (score 0):

The `img` is forcing the width of the `.containwrap` element. Might be able to add `width: 0; max-width: 100%;` to `.containwrap` so it collapses to a width narrower than the image's actual width.

Here's the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/brettdewoody/pen/NyBqQp?editors=1100) so you can try the responsiveness.

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* Safari */
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* Safari 6.1+ */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}

h1,
h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.containwrap {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-right: 50px;
  width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#container1 {
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 120px;
}

#endtitleline {
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%
}

#pagetitle {
  margin-left: auto;
}

#name,
#subtitle {
  text-align: right;
}

.header {
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* Safari */
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* Safari 6.1+ */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#pagetitle {
  font-family: 'Raleway', arial, sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

.central-img {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet" />

<header class="header">
  <aside class="sidebar">
  </aside>
  <section class="containwrap">
    <section class="container" id="container1">
      <div id="pagetitle">
        <h1 id="name">
          PORTFOLIO
        </h1>
        <h3 id="subtitle">
          FLEXBOX LAYOUT
        </h3>
      </div>
      <hr id="endtitleline">
    </section>

    <img src="https://s13.postimg.org/xkfa8rtvr/image.gif" class="central-img" />

  </section>
</header>
<section class="main">
</section>
```

Comment: It works, thank you! But I can't actually understand what happens. Can you explain in other words?